# Tkinter Window Freezes after Running a Server from Script

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, webserver, freeze

I am making a program that creates an separate python web server, the server being:

```
import os, sys
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler

webdir = '.'
port = 8000
print('Server Now Running')
os.chdir(webdir)
srvraddr = (('' , port))
srvrobj = HTTPServer(srvraddr, CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
srvrobj.serve_forever()
```

and then original program runs that server from command line:

```
def runServer(self):
    os.system('Webserver.py')
```

All of this is done with buttons in a Tkinter window.  When this function is called, the Tkinter window freezes and the next button cannot be pressed (one which would pull up a local html file in Safari, through the server).

I've looked around and it looks like I might need threading or something...

I have am left clueless as to how I would go about this.  Can provide more of my original program if necessary (it's a bit clunky).

I'm looking for a simple solution or maybe a specific reference to get me heading in the right direction.

Very new (3 months) to Python, so please keep this in mind.

Comment: when you run `os.system` then it waits till it ends. And this way `mainloop` can't do its job - receives key/mouse event, sends to widgets, redraws widgets, etc. You need module `threading` or `subprocess` to run server as separated thread/process and then `mainloop` will can do its job.

Comment: researching this now... could you give me an idea of what that would look like in this program?

Comment: [threading](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/threading.html) and [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html)

```
import subprocess

s = subprocess.Popen(['Webserver.py'])
```

or maybe it will need `python` to start script

```
s = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'Webserver.py'])
```

or you can run

```
s = subprocess.Popen(['python3', '-m', 'http.server', '--cgi', '8000'])
```

and later you can stop process

```
s.kill()
```

---

- `Popen` (without argument `shell=True`) expects argument as list
- after you close program subprocess still works so you have to kill them before you close program.

Comment: Totally worked!!! That was incredibly easy.  Here's my new function:  def runServer(self):
      nm = self.e2.get()
      fld = "/Users/peer/temp/" + self.e1.get() + "/" + nm + ".py"
      s = subprocess.Popen(['python3', fld]).  with e2 being the name of the web server file and e1 being it's created top folder.    Thanks Much

Comment: I'm now looking to see where I should put s.kill().  Remember I'm in a Tkinter window... I need to keep server running until program closes.

Comment: you can put `s.kill()` after `mainloop()` - it will be executed after you close window. Or if you have button to close window then assign function which do `s.kill()` and `window.destroy()`

Answer (score 1):

Since the exit code of the called program is the return value of the function os.system, the program is blocked until the called program exited.

Try using the non-blocking [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) instead.

Comment: So,  p = self.runServer, subprocess.Popen(p) ??? I'm lost.  Reading basics of threading now.  An example would be invaluable.